# RabbitMq 3.6.14 Erlang 20.1.2 : sending to wrong queue that we did not bind

Tags: rabbitmq

We had updated to version RabbitMq 3.6.14 Erlang 20.1.2 and we found a very weird issue .. it pushes a message in totally different another queue that is nothing related..

And it happens to only routing key * not #..

And it fixed when we rollback to version 3.6.8 Erlang 19.3

Comment: sounds strange, without other information is not possible to understand. If you can provide a way to reproduce the situation would be useful.

Comment: @Gabriele We now understood that it could be the cause from how to we try to upgrade to the new version.... we just upgrade both .. not checking which one is master or slave.. because issue still remain even we rollback to old version.. i meant it fixed the routing issue but still the wrong messages in the wrong queue.. Anyway.. the hard part is we could not reproduce in DEV.. i guess because of the amount of queues and messages are different..